# Reference to Object to be created later

Tags: python

I have a number of objects corresponding to a single measurement of `class Curve`, and an object for the whole series of measurments, say `class Series`. 
`Series` objects have references to `Curve` objects, but each `Curve` also has a `reference` back to its `Series`.

Currently, I first create the `Series` object `s`, then create the `Curve` objects `c1, c2,..` from the data while giving them a reference back to `s`, and finally assign `c1, c2,..` to `s`. However, that means I have to handle intialization stuff for `s` by hand afterwards.

I'd like to create the `Curve` objects first, and somehow give them a reference I can fill with the `Series` later without having to update it in every object.

EDIT: How it's currently happening.

```
class Curve:
    def __init__(self, series ):
        self.series=series

class Series:
    def __init__(self, curve_list=None):
        self.curve_list=curve_list


def read_data(folder):

    #create a new Series object
    new_series = Series()

    #create Curves objects given the folder where the data is saved, and the reference to a series object
    new_curves = createCurves(folder, new_Series)

    #assign the new Curve objects to the series object
    new_series.curve_list = new_curves
    #prepare the Series object for use, which needs the information of the Curve objects
    new_series.do_some_things()
```

Comment: *to handle intialization stuff for `s` by hand afterwards.* - what do mean exactly?

Comment: Read [this](http://code.activestate.com/recipes/496741-object-proxying/) article, could be helpful ;) *Short advice: you can pass to constructor of `Curve` instance of proxy class and then set "final direction" to new instance of `Series`*.

Comment: @RomanPerekhrest before I can use `s`, some actions need to be taken (mostly some clean up of the curves). Ideally, that would happen in the __init__ method, so you get a finished object back after calling the constructor. Right now, `s` doesn't have all the necessary information (ref to `c1,c2,..` ) at the moment of creation, so I have to do some stuff that should be part of the __init__ after `c1,c2,..` are created and assigned. This is cumbersome and errorprone, and I'd like something more elegant.

Comment: you could post your code with details and comments

Answer (score 0):

I would initialize the curves with empty `Series` initially, and then fill that `Series` when the series actually gets initialized. Something like:

```
class Curve:
    def __init__(self, series=None):
        self.series = series

class Series:
    def __init__(self, curve_list=None):
        self.curve_list = curve_list
        for curve in curve_list:
            curve.series = self
```

This is like what you suggested, but in reverse. But this way, you can create a bunch of curves with no associated series, and prepare them however you need to. Then, you create a series from all of them, and that series adds itself to all the curves when it has enough information to do so.